# Possible to get the message body with lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I set the MX records for my domain to the ones AWS provides for receiving emails with SES.

Now I want to process incoming emails via Lambda function.

To be more specific, I would like to scan the message body for certain keywords and perform a task based on this.

Does the lambda function get the email body? When looking through the event variable, I could only find a subject line.

All examples I found went to S3 to get the message body. Does the body really not get sent to Lambda and it is necessary to fetch it via S3?

Answer (score 0):

Message bodies can get very large. That's why you need to download them from S3.

Comment: So the only way is to store them in S3 and then load it using Lambda?

Comment: SES stores the message bodies automatically on s3. when you want to process the message body you need to download the body from S3. yes.